# Windbg, how to show more code?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am new to using windbg, I normally use debuggers such as ollydbg or dissassemblers such as ida pro.  However, I am wanting to debug 64 bit assembly code.

In ollydbg and ida pro's interface, it will show several instructions are once i.e.

```
push esi
push ecx
mov esi, [esp + 0Ch]
xor ecx, ecx
sub eax, 2
@@:
    add ecx, 2
    mov word ax, [esi + ecx]
    test ax, ax
    jnz @b
mov eax, ecx
pop ecx
pop esi
retn 4
```

However, my problem with windbg is when I set a breakpoint on $exentry and start debugging it, it will only show one instruction at a time.

Such as

push esi

Then I will step over it and it will show

push ecx

Is there any way I can make it have an ollydbg like interface, so that it will actually show all the code and let me step over it, maybe with some kind of syntax highlighting?

If it doesn't do this, is there any debugger which can debug 64 bit applications that has an ollydbg-like interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see several instrucions at once using the disassembly window which you can open like this: View | Disassembly

Answer (score 4):

You have the following options:

1. If you are using the command console, use the `u` (unassemble) command. It accept arguments. `u .` will print from the current EIP. `u` will continue the listing. `uf` will unassemble a function, `u . l300` will unassemble from current EIP 300 assembly instructions. etc.
2. You can open the disassemble window (View -> Disassembly).

By the way, you can also see assembly instructions with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason you find using dis-assembly window an annoyance but would still want to see some commands in both sides you can try this method

first execute `ub eip l4;u eip l4;p;r` 
and then single step by hitting enter instead of using p

the above command will show 4 instructions prior to eip and 4 instructions after eip

using `enter repeats the earlier command`